# How to make Django link to different html pages based on the result of a form?

Tags: python, django

I am confused on how to change html pages based on the results of a form.
I want to create a form to get a search query. Based on this query, a page should be rendered to the user. For example, if the page query is chocolate, then a page should be main/chocolate. Same for any other query: main/"query".
How is it possible to do this?

I have tried using a normal form in order to do this, but this did not work. I have tried:

this is from views.py:

````
    if request.method == "GET":
        ask = NewForm(request.GET)
        if ask.is_valid:
            Muk = ask.cleaned_data("Stuff")
            result = util.get_entry(Muk)
            good = markdown2.markdown(result)
            return page(request, good)

        else: return render(request, "encyclopedia/index.html")
    
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/layout.html", {
        "form": ask
    })```
And it always meets me with an error page, since earlier in views.py, I defined:
def page(request, name):
    ```stuff = util.get_entry(name)
   
    if stuff is None:
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/error.html")

    things = markdown2.markdown(stuff)
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/content.html", {
        "things":things
    })def page(request, name):
    stuff = util.get_entry(name)
   
    if stuff is None:
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/error.html")

    things = markdown2.markdown(stuff)
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/content.html", {
        "things":things
    })```
````

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you are asking,,,

Always use **POST** method for posting values from a form.

Get the search term from a **form** and make sure you have the **same template** available in your template directory:

**views.py :**

```
def any_name(request):
    context = {}    
    if(request.method == "POST"):
        
        template_name = request.POST.get('value of name attribute in the form element')
        
        return render(request, str(template_name) + '.html' , context)

    else:
        
        #GET method behaviour
        # render the template containing the form
```

Comment: Thank you. One question: do I need to create a Django form for this to work, or is a standard HTML form enough?

Comment: anything would do. Django forms saves time but not very customizable... custom forms take some time to build but are very customizable...